# Invalid postback or callback argument. on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have following code snippet in my asp.net webpage.

```
<div id="descDiv" style="display:none;">
<form>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="inputDesc" Height="200px" Width="100%" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" placeholder="Enter any details you know about this city" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                            <input type="button" Class="cancel" value="Cancel" OnClick="hideInput('descDiv');" /><asp:Button ID="Submit_Desc" CssClass="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Desc_Click" />
                          </form>
                        </div>
```

When I click the submit button I receive this error:

```
  Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using 
  <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or 
  <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  
  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or 
  callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  
  If the data is valid and expected, use the
  ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the
  postback or callback data for validation.
```

This form is enclosed in another main form which has 'runat' attribute. What should I do to correct this problem?

EDIT:

Here is the shortest code to reproduce the problem:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="descDiv">
            <form>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="inputDesc" Height="200px" Width="100%" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" placeholder="Enter any details you know about this city" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                  <input type="button" class="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="hideInput('descDiv');" />
                  <asp:Button ID="Submit_Desc" CssClass="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Desc_Click"/>
             </form>
         </div>
    </div>
        <form>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Height="200px" Width="100%" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" placeholder="Enter any details you know about this city" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
            <input type="button" class="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="hideInput('descDiv');" />
             <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Desc_Click"/>
        </form>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you entering any markup in the textbox?

Comment: @abhitalks no just plain text

Comment: @Tehreem, html forms can never be nested..

Comment: if you have two separate portions to be submitted, use two separate forms(only one form can have `runat="server"` attribute) .. you can have a submit button in each of the forms..

Comment: @dotNETbeginner It gives me the same error even if I take out form tag

Comment: @dotNETbeginner but I cannot run both of them on server and I need server side controls in both of them

Comment: you can place server side controls in html forms also..finally each server control is rendered into respective html markup..

Comment: post your entire aspx markup to get good idea of what you are doing..

Comment: @Tehreem, now please explain what are you trying to do exactly? what is your requirement?

Comment: I want to be able to submit one form at a time. But when I submit the form in descDiv it gives me the above mentioned error.

Comment: I need several more forms like these in my page. Each form's submit button should submit that particular form and then I will insert the textbox values to db from code behind.

Comment: first, remove the form tag above the div..and try submitting each form(have different event handler for each submit buttons)..I have not tried this though..

Comment: the one with attribute runat=server?
I tried and now it gives me this error: Control 'inputDesc' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: Sorry man..I just tried..I was wrong..only way is the cgoasduff answer in webforms.. but in mvc you can do it easily.. I am really sorry for wasting your time..

Comment: @dotNETbeginner no problem I got the solution :) I need to use validationgroups instead of multiple forms. Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have two forms on your page, remove the form tag just under your div. The one to keep has to be the form runat="server" since it's a .net page.

what you can do is use .net buttons and process whatever they do from code behind

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
     <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
</form>

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // do something with button 1

}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something with button 2
}
```

Comment: but then I will have two submit buttons in single form. Also the page won't know which part I want to submit

Comment: I am tagging this as answer because it partially answers the question. The other half is that I should use GroupValidators instead of multiple forms within a form.